# Skip logout prompt for IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I'm working on a project that has both a website and an app that use the same IdentityServer4 to authenticate users. On the website, when a user logs out, he gets a confirmation screen to ask whether he's sure he wants to log out.

The problem is that on the app, we can't show the logout prompt because, well, it's an app written in Xamarin and we can't redirect to the logout prompt page.

Is there a way to disable the logout prompt when the request comes from the app?

Comment: What is the PostLogoutRedirectUri set to on the API client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end session endpoint supports skipping confirmation if you pass a valid id_token_hint in the request.

The relevant spec is here: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPLogout

If a valid id_token is passed (i.e. the one you got when you signed in) then the OP should skip confirmation, do the sign out and then allow the user to be redirected to the post logout redirect URL (if supplied).

Comment: One more remark I found, is that there has to be a valid redirect url. If you pass along something on the localhost, then something goes wrong and IdentityServer defaults to the prompt page.

That doesn't show up when testing locally, because if the IdentityServer runs locally as well, then it can access the localhost url and everything works fine. Only when running this in the dev and test environments, things go south.

Comment: The redirect URL must be pre-registered against the client, yep.

Comment: yep, precisely speaking, the URL must be in [PostLogoutRedirectUris](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_aspnetcore_and_apis.html?highlight=PostLogoutRedirectUris#modifying-the-client-configuration)

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem and **I solved it**. This was first google response so I decided to put my answer here for others to see.

**Solution:** Inside IdentityServer4 Quick start project logic is already there and ready to configure it for user needs.

1. Open SolutionName/Quickstart/Account/AccountOptions.cs
2. Set **ShowLogoutPrompt** to false
3. Set **AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut** to true

[image: Example]

I hope this will help, good luck.