# IdentityServer4 and Angular: logout with Implicit flow

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an Angular app that integrates with IdentityServer4 with implicit flow and the angular-oauth2-oidc library.

Everything seems to work fine, I can log in; and access token is available.

If I click the logout button, I handle it like:

```
logout() {    
   this.oauthService.logOut();    
}
```

...and I'm redirected to Identity Server, where it asks me if I really want to log out.

My question is whether I can bypass that prompt? I mean, I want to log out completely if the button is clicked and redirected back to the Angular site, without the need to confirm it?

How can this be achieved?

EDIT: as mentioned in the other answers, it should work if you pass id_token_hint. So I did:

```
logout() {
    this.oauthService.customQueryParams = {
        'id_token_hint': this.oauthService.getIdToken()
    };    
    this.oauthService.logOut();    
}
```

But it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip logout prompt for IdentityServer4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48659718/skip-logout-prompt-for-identityserver4)

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49114796/5751404  also .set current id token to `id_token_hint` when sending logout request .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues I needed to fix in order to make this work.

In IdentityServer, AccountOptions class, I had to set this property to true instead of false:

```
public static bool AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut = true;
```

Next, In IdentityServer client configuration, I had to define the post logout redirect uri:

```
PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://...."}
```

That did it. I did not have to change anything in the Angular client.

Comment: Can you share the code with me? I just wanted to double check if I'm using the correct approach

Comment: PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://...."} How does this link look?